# How to schedule notification in android after application exit?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I am working on an application in which a notification has to fired after some time. The code for firing a notification is in a method. I want to execute this method after some time the application has been exited. I tried Alarm Manager, it runs fine but it needs an intent. I don't want to show an activity , I just want to show notification in status bar. Is there any other way to do this? The method I want to run is **fireNotification**.  Using Alarm Manager seems logical but It can fire an Intent not a method. I need some way to run this method when application is not running.

```
private void fireNotification(long Id, String Title)
{

    //Define sound URI
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(Title)
                    .setContentText("Tap here to view")
                    .setSound(soundUri)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);




    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ViewActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra("noteId", noteId);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    // Adds the back stack

    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ViewNoteActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent to the top of the stack

    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    // Gets a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack


    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);



    // Sets an ID for the notification
    int mNotificationId = safeLongToInt(safeLongToInt(Id));
    // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);




    // Builds the notification and issues it.
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
}



public static int safeLongToInt(long l) {
    if (l < Integer.MIN_VALUE || l > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
                (l + " cannot be cast to int without changing its value : Notification ID.");
    }
    return (int) l;
}
```

Comment: Just have your app respond to the intent by showing the notification.

Comment: @323go I want  a notification like Google keep. When reminder is set, it shows notification in status bar even if the app is not running.

Comment: I answered. Did you not understand? The app doesn't have to be running for AlarmManager. You can send the Alarm intent to your service and have the service create the notification.